# Passing JSON objects to map coordinates

Tags: ios, double

I am populating a NSArray from JSON.

The NSArray is called 'categorias', the latitude and longitude from the object are stored as double in the MySQL database.

Now I am trying to show on a mapView markers from the JSON objects.

```
 for ( int i=0;i<[categorias count];i++){

        NSString *lalitudText = [[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nombreEmpresa"];
        NSLog(@"QUE ES ESTO--> %@",lalitudText);

        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        double latitud = [[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitud"];
        double longitud = [[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitud"];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitud, longitud);
        marker.title = @"Las Palmas";
        marker.snippet = @"Gran Canaria";
        marker.map = mapView_;

    }
```

At following lines I am getting a compiler warning:

```
double latitud = [[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitud"];
double longitud = [[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitud"];
```

The warning is:

```
Initializing 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `[[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitud"]` will be an `NSNumber` or `NSString` instance. You can't directly store a `double` (or any other primitive) in a dictionary.

So, you need to convert that instance to a double:

```
[[[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitud"] doubleValue]
```

(which will fortunately work for `NSNumber` and `NSString` instances)

Answer (score 1):

Just convert `NSNumber` to `double`:

```
double latitud = [[[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitud"] doubleValue];
double longitud = [[[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitud"]doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double latitud = [[[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitud"] doubleValue];
double longitud = [[[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitud"] doubleValue];
```